# How to get value of Vue Switch component

Tags: vue.js

I have placed a vs-switch component and trying to pass different value(Yes & No) when in true and false state. But due to some error only null values are being inserted. Please help

```
<vs-switch color="danger" icon-pack="feather" vs-icon-on="icon-check-circle" vs-icon-off="icon-slash" v-model="newRecord.leadtype" vs-value="Yes">
    <span slot="on">YES</span>
   <span slot="off">NO</span>
</vs-switch>
```

Comment: Where is `vs-switch` from?  I did a quick google and found that vuesax and vuexy both define a `vs-switch` component.

Comment: the component is from vuexy .

Comment: Share your vue js source please